# Angularjs dropdown multiselect issues

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, ng-dropdown-multiselect

**Summary :**

I am using angularjs-dropdown-multiselect directive.

**Reference :** [AngularJS Dropdown Multiselect](http://dotansimha.github.io/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect/#/)

**Problems facing :**

**Problem 1 :**
I want to use `onItemSelect` & `onItemDeselect` events when user select or deselect the options from the dropdown.

I configure them successfully but problem is that without select any option also these events are executing frequently.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-dropdown-multiselect="" options="listClientCompany" selected-model="selectedClients" extra-settings="clientSelectionSettings" translation-texts="translations" events="onItemSelect(selectedClients);onItemDeSelect(selectedClients)"></div>
```

**Controller :**

```
$scope.selectedClients = []; 
$scope.clientSelectionSettings = {idProp: '_id',displayProp:'name',externalIdProp : "_id",enableSearch:false,scrollableHeight: '200px',scrollable:true};   
$scope.translations = {buttonDefaultText: 'Select'};

$scope.onItemSelect = function(item) {
  console.log(item); // execute multiple times on page load also without selecting any option from the dropdown.
}
```

**Screenshot :**

[image]

**I also tried the solution defined here :**

https://github.com/dotansimha/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect/issues/39. But didn't get any success.

**Problem 2:**
When ever i removed `$scope.selectedClients = [];` from the controller it gives me this error in the console.

```
Error: [$interpolate:interr] Can't interpolate: {{getButtonText()}} 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.19/$interpolate/interr?p0=%7B%7BgetButtonTe…%A0&p1=TypeError%3A%20Cannot%20read%20property%20'length'%20of%20undefined
    at http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:78:12
    at Object.$interpolate.fn (http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:8756:26)
    at Scope.$digest (http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:12426:40)
    at Scope.$apply (http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:12699:24)
    at done (http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:8287:45)
    at completeRequest (http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:8499:7)
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange (http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:8438:11) angular.js:9959
```

**I also tried the solution defined here :**

https://github.com/dotansimha/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect/issues/22 but didn't get any success.

Comment: what are the options? object or value?

Comment: Options are coming from the api..and are working fine.

Comment: sure but if its an  object or single value it cant be an array

Answer (score 0):

you always send the array to the function 
you should do so

```
$scope.selectedClients = []; 
$scope.selectedClient = {};
$scope.clientSelectionSettings = {idProp: '_id',displayProp:'name',externalIdProp : "_id",enableSearch:false,scrollableHeight: '200px',scrollable:true};   
$scope.translations = {buttonDefaultText: 'Select'};

$scope.onItemSelect = function(item) {
  //then you can push your object to the array
  console.log(item); // execute multiple times on page load also without selecting any option from the dropdown.
}
```

and

```
<div ng-dropdown-multiselect="" options="listClientCompany" selected-model="selectedClient" extra-settings="clientSelectionSettings" translation-texts="translations" events="onItemSelect(selectedClient);onItemDeSelect(selectedClient)"></div>
```